# Isn't importing all your Angular modules and controllers in the index.html file inefficient?

Tags: angularjs, import, dependencies

In most Angular examples I see, for example, the well-known [Sample Angular App](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app), all of the Angular related code is imported as one huge file.

In other cases, an `index.html` file has about 20 imports, consisting of modules, controllers, services, etc. In most cases a controller is only needed for one particular state, or page.

Is there a more efficient yet simple way to import all of them for when they're needed?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is a way to lazy load additional files/modules when needed. This is unfortunately not built-in in Angular, but you can use ocLazyLoad as module to do the trick:

https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad

I also work with this module and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Cool tip, but it doesn't exactly answer the question of whether or not this is a good thing, performance-wise

Comment: Having all your code (minified) in one file is usually performance wise a lot faster than having lots of small files that are loaded separately.